# Desktop application cannot connect to database but web application can

Tags: c#, database, desktop-application, sql-server-2012

I have written a C# desktop (winforms) application which is essentially a clone of a web application I wrote. The web application is able to talk back and forth with the database just fine. However, when I install the desktop application, I get the following error:

*A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server*

I am using the exact same connection string in the desktop application as I am using in the web app which looks like this:

```
"Data Source=tcp:s08.winhost.com;Initial Catalog=THEDATABASE;
            User ID=USERNAME;Password=******;Integrated Security=False;"
```

I am unable to use SQL Server Configuration Manager as my databases are hosted on Winhost.com. However they have made it clear to me that the proper ports are open, named pipes are on and SQL Browser is configured correctly. If anyone has had a similar problem, please let me know what you did to resolve this issue. I have also included the entire error below.

Thanks

`************** Exception Text **************`
`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`

Comment: Is the web application on the same machine? Have you checked that the firewall is turned off?

Comment: This is probably a silly question, but did you allow the application through your firewall?

Comment: There may be more information buried in the exception to tell you more about what's going on. Drill into the `InnerException` property (and remember that the nested exception may itself have a nested exception). Also, check the `Data` property for any additional information - ADO.NET is particularly good at putting helpful details in that dictionary.

Comment: holeydood3,
Yes, I turned off the firewall. Here's something else that is strange. The desktop app works just fine on my home computers (both the one I developed it on and my wife's computer) but it will not work at all outside of my home. What's strange is that I don't have any references to any local databases in my connection strings. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, the web application is on the same machine. I did try and turn my firewall off and it still did not work properly.

Comment: @JoshuaBates Have you tried running the application as an Admin? It could be a permission issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove TCP protocol name and port number and try with full hosting website address..something like this

```
  Data Source=www.winhost.com;Initial Catalog=THEDATABASE;
             User ID=USERNAME;Password=**;Integrated Security=False;
```

Comment: I was thinking doing this when I got home. Please check my comment to holydood3 regarding the application working on my home machine but not any other computers outside of my home, despite there being no references to localhost or local databases in the code, configuration, or connection strings. I will definitely try this out when I get home, though. Thank you.

Comment: removing the tcp worked combined with the proper port. thanks to you all!

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found that the problem was a proxy server. The application is being used by corporations who have proxy servers setup and due to this port 1433 was blocked. I ended up resolving the issue by creating a webservice.